# La base de datos no quiere conectarse con el host

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Estoy tratando de conectarte a mi base de datos MySQL, no quiere reconocer el localhost, rebota con error:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine  
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker  


eng = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb:///host='localhost', user='root',   passwd='...',port='3307', database='Nomina_jul15',echo=True")  

connection = eng.connect()
```

me genera este error:

> _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError)   MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")

Con pymsql:

```
eng = create_engine("mysql+pymysql:///....
```

Me arroja este error:

```
([WinError 10061] No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de   destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión)")
```

Estoy algo confundido porque con MySQL y sentencias SQL funciona normal, puedo hacer los cambios y consultas que necesito.

Comment: Hola, me suena a un problema de configuración por el lado de MySQL. ¿Has movido o cambiado algo ahí?

Comment: he reistalado el modulo mysql en python pero la bd funciona bien con mysql y worbench, no responde es con sqlalchemy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que el tema es tu cadena de conexión:

```
eng = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb:///host='localhost', user='root',   passwd='...',port='3307', database='Nomina_jul15',echo=True")
```

De acuerdo a la documentación para [MySQL-Python](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqldb), debería ser algo así:

```
mysql+mysqldb://<user>:<password>@<host>[:<port>]/<dbname>
```

Por lo tanto, intenta cambiar código a:

```
eng = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:password@localhost:3307/Nomina_jul15",echo=True)
```

Comment: No incluiria el password?

Comment: @Jsierra2017 está incluido el password

Comment: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError)   (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Comment: con ese codigo el error es diferente

Comment: niega el acceso a ese usuario

Comment: @Jsierra2017 es el usuario que tu estás usando en tu ejemplo, funciona ese usuario desde el Workbench?

Comment: @Jsierra2017 reemplaza root por el usuario que tiene acceso y obviamente tienes que usar el password correcto.

Comment: si no tengo problema en worbench, esa bd la ejecuto normal, con mysql

Comment: mi usuario sigue siendo root, no lo he cambiado

Comment: @Jsierra2017 la conexión ya se ha podido establecer, ese era el problema, ¿no? Ahora el problema parace ser otro

Comment: @Jsierra2017 te recomiendo que crees otra pregunta para saber por qué no puedes conectarte con ese usuario, muestra los GRANTS y privilegios que has usado para el usuario root así como la configuración de tu MySQL

Comment: con el cambio de pasword me sale lo siguiente:  varias filas    
2017-08-15 14:58:12,666 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()  eso confirmaria la conexion entonces? o no?

Comment: listo cesar, gracias yo la organizo y la cargo con los detalles que pides?